# I need to traverse to and store id of anchor tag

Tags: jquery, find, parent, traversal, closest

OK, I have been trying to obtain the id of a particular link, but attr('id') keeps returning undefined.

Here is the structure of the html:

```
<hr />

<span>The Huffs</span><br />

            <img src="images/thumbnails/websitethumbs/graphicdesign/logos/th_2.jpg" height="120"><br />

            <span>the huff family<span><br />

            <span>$10.99<span><a id="btn_2" class="btn hidden" href="cart.php?add=2"> add</a><br />

            <form method="post">

                <select class="sizeSelect" id="size_2">

                <option value="0">Select Size</option><option value="7x5">7x5</option><option value="16x12">16x12</option><option value="10x10">10x10</option></select>

                <span> + $<span class="shipping" id="shipping_2"></span> shipping</span>

            </form>

<hr />
```

And I want to traverse from #size_2 to the a tag with the id #btn_2, and I need to grab that ID and save it to a variable.

I have been using the following jquery code:

```
   $('.sizeSelect').change(function(size) {
     sizeId = $(this).attr('id');
     addBtn = $(sizeId).parent().closest('.btn').attr('id');
     ...
```

so I want add btn to return "btn_2" but it only return "undefined." I have tried prev() instead of closest also... well I have tried lots of stuff. Hours into this and I would really appreciate some insight :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using `$(sizeId)` instead of `$(this)`? Anyway it would need to be `$('#'+sizeId)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
$('.sizeSelect').change(function() {
  var sizeId = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1]; // gets 2 from size_2
  //since id's are unique
  var addBtn = "btn_"+sizeId; //anchor id  
});
```

Comment: Great! I changed it a bit since I was already using "lastChar = sizeId.substr(sizeId.length - 1);" and then I just built addBtn from that. thnx a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code:

```
sizeId = $(this).attr('id');
addBtn = $(sizeId).parent().closest('.btn').attr('id');
```

In your case the ID of `.sizeSelect` is `size_2`, so

```
sizeId == 'size_2';
```

so what you are doing is actually

```
addBtn = $('size_2')
```

and it should be

```
addBtn = $('#size_2')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your code a little bit from

```
addBtn = $(sizeId).parent().closest('.btn').attr('id');
```

to

```
addBtn = $('#'+sizeId).parent().siblings('.btn').attr('id');
```